# How to get specific text from a string?

Tags: python, string

The string below is what I receive as output and I specifically want the numbers within the square brackets.

```
4 requests to https://twitter.com/search?f=live&lang=en&q=from%3AUsername&src=spelling_expansion_revert_click failed, giving up.
[3962342629375400258]
```

I have attempted split(), but is there an efficient way of extracting it?

Comment: Try splitting on `\n`

Comment: Is the length of the number fixed?

Comment: Regex is an option: `import re; re.findall(r'\[(\d+)\]', your_string)`

Comment: No the length of the number varies from user to user.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I will try this thanks!

Comment: If would help if you could [edit] and add the data as a string literal, and what you've tried exactly. For reference, see [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp, worked well!!!

Comment: @AnonymousProgrammer please do not add Solved to your title. This question has visible answers, you can choose to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that best solves your problem. If your answer has been resolved in the comments you can encourage that user to post their answer in the answer field to be accepted. In any case, the system cannot know this question has an accepted answer just by adding the word solved to the title.

Answer (score 0):

this code does it find the index of the opening bracket and closing one and cuts the string between those 2 indexes and u get the string between the brackets

```
string[string.index("[")+1:string.index("]")]
```

accommodating for @geraldmayr's commend you can delete all the brackets before the ones u want to segment with this code:

```
string = "fjusfausbfhj[sdfsdfsfsf][1231231231]"

string = string.split("[")[len(string.split("["))-1][:-1]

print(string)
```

Comment: This will not work if square brackets are contained in the first line.

Comment: I think u don't have read the example and question right @geraldmayr

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use find:

```
s[s.find("[")+1:s.find("]")]
```

Comment: You meant `find("]")`. But also here, this will not work if square brackets are contained in the first line.

Comment: typo!.. big fingers.. and it's not the case here in the given example so it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

In the case that your *number in brackets* is always on a separate line without any other prefixes or suffixes except the square brackets and an optional trailing new line, I would use:

```
s = '...\n[1234]'
s.rstrip().rsplit(sep='\n', maxsplit=1)[-1].removeprefix('[').removesuffix(']')
```

First we ensure to remove any trailing whitespace including a trailing new line. Then we separate the string into two parts, but avoid any unnecessary splitting once we have found the last line beginning from the end of the string. Afterwards we select the last line from the list and remove the brackets.